# I deleted /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default. How to regenerate

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I wanted to install ssl certificate. I tried to restart nginx but it failed. I saved a copy before deleting default file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ . original default file was looking blue on terminal. I have recreated default file with old working configurations. But it looks grey on terminal now And I cannot restart nginx service. it is always failed. I don't know how to make it blue again and back to old settings. I think Original file had some file permissions or something else. Could you help please ? Droplet is Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original copy should still be in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`, unless you deleted that as well. If it's still there, you can recreate the symlink in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Comment: Yes. it worked. it came back. :) Thank you so much. I used rm default to delete it. Then what I deleted if it was there ?

Comment: The file you deleted was the symlink in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` which pointed to `/etc/nginx/sites-available`. You didn't delete the original file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`. The advantage of using symlinks in `sites-enabled` is that you can temporarily disable a sites by deleting the symlink, then re-enable later by recreating the symlink.